# SQL query to group data

Tags: mysql, sql, database, t-sql

There is a requirement that I need to fill a `group-id` in a table as combination of `item-id` and `auto-id`. The table is as follows;

```
----------------------------------------
Item_id  |  Auto_id  |  Group_id
----------------------------------------
1        |  1        |  1 
1        |  2        |  1
2        |  3        |  3
2        |  4        |  3
3        |  5        |  5
3        |  6        |  5
3        |  7        |  5
4        |  8        |  8
4        |  9        |  8
5        |  10       |  10
6        |  11       |  11
```

The two columns would be populated already that is `Item_id` and `Auto_id`, and we need to fill `group_id`. The relation would be like for each repetitive `item_id` the `group_id` would be minimum of `auto_id`.

I hope I make it clear. If possible please help.

Thanks,
Ashish

Comment: Shouldn't that be `Group_id = 3` for 3rd and 4th row? (where Item_id = 2)

Comment: Yes Nenad. Corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a subquery, with a group by, where you calculate the minimum auto_id for each item_id. Then you can join this subquery with the original table:

```
SELECT t1.Item_id, t1.Auto_id, t2.Group_id
FROM
  yourtable t1 INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Item_Id, MIN(Auto_id) Group_id
    FROM yourtable
    GROUP BY Item_Id) t2
  ON t1.Item_Id=t2.ItemId
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2601/1).

If you need to update an existing column, you could use this UPDATE query:

```
UPDATE
  yourtable t1 INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Item_Id, MIN(Auto_id) Group_id
    FROM yourtable
    GROUP BY Item_id) t2
  ON t1.Item_Id=t2.Item_Id
SET
  t1.Group_id=t2.Group_id
```

Fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed99a/1).